# Android Studio update 1.0 breaks NDK compilation

Tags: android-ndk, android-studio

I just updated from 0.8.14 to 1.0 RC4 and now my NDK support seems broken.

The failing ndk-build call:
`C:\Users\layer0\AppData\Local\Android\android-ndk32-r10b-windows-x86_64\ndk-build.cmd NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null     APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\layer0\AndroidStudioProjects\GameEngine\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-20
NDK_OUT=C:\Users\layer0\AndroidStudioProjects\GameEngine\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\layer0\AndroidStudioProjects\GameEngine\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib APP_ABI=all`

Error message from make:
make.exe: *** No rule to make target     `C:\Users\layer0\AndroidStudioProjects\GameEngine\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/my-jni/C_\Users\layer0\AndroidStudioProjects\GameEngine\app\src\main\jni', 
needed by C:\Users\layer0\AndroidStudioProjects\GameEngine\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/my-jni/C_\Users\layer0\AndroidStudioProjects\GameEngine\app\src\main\jni\buffercopies.o'.  Stop.`

The whole project, including the JNI parts was compiling fine just hours ago before the update. I guess something changed in the configs or about the supported ABIs?
But i don't really know what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it down, think, try again ... find a solution. *grrrr*
Effect was this bug:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66937
Issue 66937: "no rule to make target" when compiling only one .c file with ndk-build.cmd launched from gradle
Once the .so files are created the dummy.c file can be removed. I did that and forgot about the bug, so it came back after the update.

Comment: Sure. Just had to wait the two days.

Comment: Can you explain in your answer how to get NDK in a project?